# How to annotate generator with Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I want to annotate generators with Flow like this:

```js
// @flow

function* generator(): Generator<number, void, any> {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}
```

But Flow coverage rate doesn't become 100%.
3 'yield's are colored red.

```
$ npx flow coverage --color generator.js
// @flow

function* generator(): Generator<number, void, any> {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

Covered: 57.14% (4 of 7 expressions)
```

How can I work this correctly?

Comment: The type is correct, and there's no need to add more. Could be a bug with `flow coverage`?